# Using Twilio to leave ringless voicemail messages

Tags: twilio

I have been looking and asking for information on this subject and getting nothing. I suspect that it is just a command in the data packet array. Any clues would be helpful.
Can call $_REQUEST array be modified to inject needed code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking. Can you reword the body of your question to include the question and anything you have tried so far?

Answer (score 12):

Leaving ringless voice mail drops with Twilio requires that you POST an api request to make a call single call to a phone number then a fraction of a second later make a second request to the same number while immediately dropping the first request.  This results in the mobile company routing the second call directly to their voicemail servers.

As far as I know Twilio doesn't offer any "out of the box" voicemail drop options in their RESTful API.

Comment: any other details? what do the timeouts look like? which occurs first: dropping the call or initiating the second call?

Comment: I've never actually developed the system, only read about it & have used Twilio API for other projects.  I think it's safe to assume that dropping the first call only happens after the second has connected.  I don't have timeout details.  To be honest, this setup is likely against Twilio's TOS since they don't charge for calls that don't connect (the first POST) which means you'll be using their resources for free and that's a big no no.

Comment: I have confusions, where will we receive the voice-drop in our phone or in twilio call log? And from where we will dial two calls? Can you please explain the flow? I want it for my product. @CoreyShowers

Comment: Ringless Voicemail is against Twilio's Acceptable Use Policy, specifically our clauses around short duration calls prohibit the double-call approach. It's also illegal in some jurisdictions. Instead, consider using our AMD service to detect if you reach a person or voicemail, then leave a recording or say a message.